# The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class. zf3 with routes to several controllers in one module

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, routes, zend-framework3

When i'm trying to create routes to several controllers in one module and i'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boDH4.png)

```
        'application' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/application[/:action]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'vehicles' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/vehicles[/:action]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\VehiclesController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Calling the `indexAction()` of `IndexController` works perfectly. However it doesn't work for `VehiclesController`. I tried to invoke `VehiclesController` in `factories` - unsuccessful.

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        Controller\VehiclesController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
    ],
```

Using `ServiceManager` function

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\VehiclesController::class => function($sm){
            $vehiclesService=$sm->get('Application\Model\VehiclesTable');
            return new Controller\VehiclesController($vehiclesService);
        }
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are doing something like below to invoke your controllers in your `module.config.php`

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Therefore, you may be using same controller name twice under `factories` key. It may be as above or different way.

So define them once under `factories` subkey of `controllers` key as the following

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        Controller\VehiclesController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Comment: i just invoked controllers under `factories` like in your issue. Tried to invoke it using `ServiceManager` function too, also not working.

Comment: Do you have any cached files in the `data` folder in your app? If it does, please delete all of them and try again. I see you are passing some service via controller's constructor, for this, you must create a factory for your controller. In this case using `InvokableFactory::class` wont work.